# SELECT WHERE date time greater than day (and not necessarily time)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a datetime column. I wish to return all the records whose date is greater than the input date. I used a date picker control for input date.

In other words, if my data table has only four rows,

```
2014-04-23 10:40:27.592 Abby
2014-05-23 09:40:27.592 Bobby
2014-06-01 08:53:59.320 Cathy
2014-06-05 08:53:59.320 Debbie
```

When my DatePicker control has input of **2014-06-03**, the output should be:

```
2014-06-05 08:53:59.320 Debbie
```

The convert the value of dateTimePicker Control to string before calling the select method.

```
string FromDate = dateTimePickerFromDate.ToString()
```

In my select method, I have:

```
if (fromDate != null)
{
    return GetSQLDataSet(" [employeeKnownAs]  + ' ' +[employeeLastName] AS 'empName', [InsertDate]", "EmpData", "", "EmpData.InsertDate >= " + fromDate.ToString(), "InsertDate ASC", DbConnect.myDataConnection);
```

Unfortunately, it return null no matter what dates I choose from the dateTimePicker.

Comment: You want suggestion specific to SQL/C#?

Comment: Yes, C# would be optimal.

Comment: Your DatePicker anyways returns DATE part only. So, you will have to CAST your SQL DATETIME value to DATE in your SQL query.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You might want to look at the actual query being sent to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DatePicker anyways returns DATE part only as you have mentioned in your post `my DatePicker control has input of 2014-06-03`. So, you will have to `CAST` your SQL DATETIME value to DATE in your SQL query. Your Query  should look something like

```
select 
[employeeKnownAs],
[employeeLastName] AS 'empName', 
[InsertDate]
from EmpData
where cast(InsertDate as DATE) >=  fromDate.ToString()
```

You can as well use SQL SERVER `CONVERT()` function with style format `101` like

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,InsertDate,101) >= fromDate.ToString()
```

Comment: I think I get your idea. tried the code below as you suggested but it still returns null. having a complier error saying ` "Incorrect syntax near ','." `, ` My code is below: `return GetSQLDataSet("[employeeKnownAs]  + ' ' + [employeeLastName] AS 'empName',  [InsertDate]", "EmpData", "", "CAST(InsertDate AS DATE) = " + fromDate, "InsertDate ASC", DbConnect.MyDataConnection);` fromDate is String by itself so there is no need to convert it to string

Comment: @CherylGuo, Compiler error et all have to be handled by you; can't help there. per your post; problem was SQL specific which has been answered and if you run the query in myanswer as-is in SSMS it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

So you need convert datetime into correct string?

```
string FromDate = dateTimePickerFromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```